# Check if userinput matches any digits of a (random) integer

Tags: python, random, integer, selection

```
random = random.randint(1000, 9999)
guess = int(input("Enter your guess: "))
while guess != random:
    guess = int(input("That was incorrect! Enter your guess: "))
```

This works as a very simple guessing game, however I would like to include something where after every unsuccessful try it would say how many numbers out of the four digit number were correct.

I have not attempted this, mainly because I'm not sure how this could be done.

e.g

```
random = 1234
Enter your guess: 1111
You guessed 1 number correct
Enter your guess: 1222
You guessed 2 numbers correct
...... and so on
```

Comment: You could convert both numbers to string using `str(number)` and then iterate through them, character by character, and increase a counter variable when the characters in both are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant with positions

```
random = random.randint(1000, 9999)
guess = int(input("Enter your guess: "))
while guess != random:
    right = 0
    index = 0
    for char in str(guess):
        if char == str(random)[index]:
            index += 1
            right += 1
    print(f'{right} were right')
    guess = int(input("That was incorrect! Enter your guess: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to keep both numbers as int, you could use % (modulo operator) to find the remainder of your integer once divided by its base-10 value.

For example.

```py
    correctnum = 0
    random = 1234
    guess = 1111
    if ((((random-(random % 1000 )) /1000) == (((guess-(guess % 1000 )) /1000)):
      correctnum++
```

Formula repeated for 100/10/1 should all compare numbers in that "spot" without having to convert datatypes. Follow that up with an output of the value of correctnum and you should have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
random = 1234
random = str(random)

#guess = str(input('enter your guess'))
guess = '1222'
correct = 0
for i in range(len(guess)):
    if guess[i] == random[i]:
        correct += 1

print(correct)
ouput: 2
```

or simply:

```
correct = sum(guess[i] == random[i] for i in range(len(guess)))
```